# Any easy, noncluttering way to set up "mydomain.com/username" using PHP?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Simply put, when a user wants people to be able to go to their profile, we want them to be able to just say go to `mydomain.com/username`. The real user page would be at something like `mydomain.com/users/page.php?id=1325` which doesn't really help users.

The problem: I've been doing PHP for some time, and have never had the need to do this. I don't have a clue where to even start? I wouldn't want to do something as naive as just creating actual folders with redirects in them or something....

Can anybody tell me how to go about this in php?

Y'all are the greatest!

Comment: One thing to think about: surely, you have URLs other than user profiles on your site.  What happens when someone creates an account named "index.php", "faq", "tos", "users", etc.?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Provided you are on an apache server look up `.htaccess` and `mod_rewrite`, it all happens outside of PHP.

Example for your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)([\/]?)$ /user/profile.php?name=$1 [L]
```

Comment: mod_rewrites are about as confusing as they can be but I got it. Thanks a lot. Perfect.